# i am building code to extact text from image if the pdf has images inside it "pytesseract" and "PyMuPDF"

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract, pymupdf

below code is giving me error : Error processing image: 'dict' object has no attribute 'width', below code is read pdf images from pdf and if pdf has image it should extract text from that image and check for provided list of keywords (method is not added here just for saving some effort )

```py
import os
import pytesseract
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from PIL import Image

def extract_text_from_image(image):
    try:
**        image = Image.frombytes("RGB", (image, image.height), image.samples) **
        image = image.convert("L")  # Convert to grayscale
        extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--oem 3 --psm 6')
        return extracted_text
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error and continue processing
        print(f"Error processing image: {str(e)}")
        return ""

def process_pdf(pdf_path):
    try:
        doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
        total_pages = doc.page_count
        for i in range(total_pages):
            page = doc[i]
            image_list = page.get_images(full=True)
            if image_list:
                for img in image_list:
                    xref = img[0]
                    base_image = doc.extract_image(xref)
                    extracted_text = extract_text_from_image(base_image)
                    # Process the extracted text (e.g., check for keywords)
                    # Log relevant information
                    print(f"Page {i + 1}/{total_pages}: Extracted text: {extracted_text}")
            else:
                print(f"Page {i + 1}/{total_pages}: No images found")
            # Show progress to the user
            progress_percent = (i + 1) / total_pages * 100
            print(f"Processing progress: [{'#' * int(progress_percent / 2):50s}] {progress_percent:.2f}%")
        # Check file size
        file_size_mb = os.path.getsize(pdf_path) / (1024 * 1024)
        if file_size_mb > 10:  # Adjust the threshold as needed
            print(f"File size ({file_size_mb:.2f} MB) exceeds threshold. Moving to the next file.")
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error and continue processing other files
        print(f"Error processing PDF {pdf_path}: {str(e)}")


process_pdf(r"your_pdf.pdf")
```

Comment: If you PyMuPDF, you do not need pytesseract, because there is a native Tesseract-OCR built into PyMuPDF. Once you have extracted an image, convert it to A `fitz.Pixmap` and OCR that directly.

Comment: can you please share snippet for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF - nothing else is needed
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

for page in doc:
    for item in page.get_images():
        xref = item[0]
        pix = fitz.Pixmap(doc, xref)  # make Pixmap from image
        # OCR the image, make a 1-page PDF from it
        pdfdata = pix.pdfocr_tobytes()  # 1-page PDF in memory
        ocrpdf = fitz.open("pdf", pdfdata)  # open as PDF document
        ocrtext = ocrpdf[0].get_text()  # extract OCR-ed text from page 1
        # ... do something with the text
        # note: text details / metadata / positions etc. are available too
```

In a similar way, you can OCR any image, e.g. present in a file, using its filename:

1. Make a pixmap from the image file: `pix = fitz.Pixmap("image.file")`.
2. Make a 1-page PDF with embedded OCRed text in memory: `pdfdata = pix.pdfocr_tobytes()  # returns a bytes object`
3. Make a PDF document from these bytes: `doc = fitz.open("pdf", pdfdata)`.
4. Load first (and only) page of that document: `page = doc[0]`.
5. Extract text as usual: `text = page.get_text()`.

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: I am getting below error with the above code snippet 

pdfdata = pix.pdfocr_tobytes()  # 1-page PDF in memory
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fitz\__init__.py", line 9930, in pdfocr_tobytes
    raise RuntimeError('No OCR support: TESSDATA_PREFIX not set')
RuntimeError: No OCR support: TESSDATA_PREFIX not set

Comment: Thanks @jorj , i found the solution for above code i have to add the testdata path and its worked for me, However is there any way i can check if that PDF has any images inside it? or not if so only then above code works for me ?

Comment: Yes, you can check if there are images on a page - in multiple ways. Easiest is `page.get_image_info()`. A list of dictionaries with image metadata including positions. If empty list, then there are no images.